# How to show the data source as an anchor tag in the popup message

Tags: javascript

My popup content variable looks like below and I would like to add the data source as an anchor tag(url) inside the popup content. I tried a lot but always get syntax error.

```
var popupContent = "<p class='infowindow'> Estimated Population in 2018 in the state of "+feature.properties.State+" was: " + feature.properties.Pop_2018 +"</p>";
```

Comment: Could you specify what indeed you want to add and to where? Add example of the errors and your attempts. This will help us to answer your question.

Comment: I want to add the source of the data inside of the popup content message. For example, I want to have a popup message like below.

Estimate Population in 2018 in the state of Colorado was:3847599 
Source of Data: https://www.census.gov

The function is already defined and I only want to modify the popup contents

Comment: so you want to add a link into your `<p>` ?

Comment: Correct. Inside the <p> Its easy to add an anchor tag in html, but in JavaScript its a bit tricky.

Comment: Why is it tricky? Add `+ "<a href=''>Source</a>" +` before your closing `</p>` tag and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what do you want. but may i guess i can help you with this solution.

```js
  var title = "Population Census";
  var State="chicago";
  var Pop_2018="3847599";
  var Data_Source="http://worldpopulationreview.com/us-cities/chicago-population/";
  var popupContent='Estimated Population in 2018 in the state of '+State+' was: '+ Pop_2018 +' DataSource: <a href="'+Data_Source+'">census.gov</a>';

  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
  $("#popUp2").attr({"data-original-title": title, "data-content": popupContent});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="#" id="popUp2" data-toggle="popover"  data-html="true">popup</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He doesn't need anything about `data-` attributes, look at the comment below his section.